# Pleasure of watching someone work

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that the describes the pleasure of watching someone else work?

For example, my mother enjoys watching me hard at work because generally she is the one working hard.

Comment: Ergoskepsis? “I like work: it fascinates me. I can sit and look at it for hours.”  ([Jerome K. Jerome](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/3352.Jerome_K_Jerome))

Comment: Look up 'vicarious' - it's not specific to work though.

Comment: You could be talking about a bunch of different words, depending on exactly which meaning you're going for. Is she proud? Relieved? Is she punishing you? Something else?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I'd say relieved and satisfied, yet at the same time enjoying the fact that I am struggling. Perhaps it is also related to karma.

Comment: In that case, WS2's answer below of Schadenfreude is what I was going to say. You're talking about a bunch of different feelings though, so you aren't going to find a single word that wraps them all up nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One does get a certain amount of *Schadenfreude* from seeing one's children put through all the torment which they exacted of one, in their youth.

Answer (score 1):

Using schadenfreude, literally translated "harm-joy" (Wikipedia) seems extremely problematic here, as it associates work directly with pain or harm.

Mudita - the pleasure of seeing others succeed or prosper would be equally suited in this case, the act of working being a neutral act in every sense except one derived from popular culture, e.g. "Work sucks".